# C linux: Simular comportamiento shell con pipes

Tags: c, linux, pipe

como el título indica estoy tratando de realizar un ejercicio para emular el comportamiento de la shell en la ejecución de una sentencia con la forma
`comando1 argumento1 | comando2 argumento2`. 
Este programa abre un pipe y crea un hijo mediante la llamada a `fork()`, además el padre ejecuta `comando1 argumento1` y redirecciona la salida estándar al extremo de escritura del pipe.
El hijo por su parte ejecuta `comando1 argumento1` y en este caso la entrada estándar debe duplicarse con el extremo de lectura del pipe.

Estoy probando mi programa mediante la ejecución de `./shell echo holaa | wc -c`, mi programa me devuelve un 47, cuando debería devolver 6, ya que son los chars de la palabra "holaa" más el caracter de fin de fichero '\0', y además es lo que devuelve la shell de linux si ejecuto el comando en ella.

Toda ayuda es bienvenida y gracias por adelantado, dejo el código de mi programa más abajo, un saludo.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Probar el programa con ./shell echo holaa | wc -c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if(argc < 6) {
                printf("Uso: comando1 argumento1 | comando2 argumento2\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        int descf[2]; //descf[0] -> lectura, descf[1] -> escritura
        int res1, res2;
        char *cmd1[] = {argv[1], argv[2], NULL};
        char *cmd2[] = {argv[4], argv[5], NULL};

        // Creamos la tuberia sin nombre
        pipe(descf);
        // Si no ha habido errores (-1) fork() retorna dos veces, una con un pid = 0 (ejecución proceso hijo) y otra con un pid > 0 (ejecución proceso padre)
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid == -1) {
                perror("Error en el fork()");
        } else if(pid > 0) { // Ejecución del padre:
                close(descf[1]);
                dup2(descf[0], 0); // Redirecciona salida estandar al extremo de escritura del pipe
                res1 = execvp(cmd1[0], cmd1); //Ejecuta comando1 argumento 1
                if(res1 == -1) perror("Fallo en execvp1()");
        } else if(pid == 0) { // Ejecución del hijo
                close(descf[0]);
                dup2(descf[1], 1); // Duplica la entrada estandar con el extremo de lectura del pipe
                res2 = execv(cmd2[0], cmd2); // Ejecuta comando2 argumento 2
                if(res2 == -1) perror("Fallo en execvp2()");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, según el manual de la función `exec()` el segundo argumento es un array de `char*` con los argumentos del comando, así como el comando en cuestión y un último elemento con valor `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Uso: comando1 argumento1 | comando2 argumento2\n"` tiene... ¡¡47 caracteres!! Que coinciden con el valor de 47 que te da la ejecución. La coincidencia indica que los parámetros no le llegan bien al programa<sup>1</sup>.

El problema es que al hacer

> ./shell echo holaa | wc -c

el propio shell de linux primero ve el `|` y te divide la instrucción en dos procesos:

- `./shell echo holaa`
- `wc -c`

y después te ejecuta ambos, poniendo el propio shell el encadenamiento de E/S.

No podría ser de otra forma, ya que necesita eso para detectar los encadenamientos, redirecciones, comodines, etc.

Para evitar que el shell de linux interfiera con tu comando, ponlo entre comillas.

> ./shell "echo holaa | wc -c"

Esto te llegará como un solo parámetro a tu ejecutable y tendrás que romperlo en tokens (primero por el `|`, luego por espacios en blanco<sup>2</sup>.

También podrías hacer

> ./shell echo holaa "|" cat -

pero como estás haciendo un "shell" tiene poco sentido.

Como nota adicional, te será mucho más útil hacer la prueba con `cat -`, que simplemente saca por salida estándar su entrada estándar:

> ./shell echo holaa | cat -

para ver el mensaje de error.

> ./shell "echo holaa | cat -"

para ver `holaa` (cuando hayas ajustado tu programa).

---

<sup>1</sup>Si el resultado hubiera sido 42, habríamos podido sospechar que se trata de alguna cuestión relacionada con [el sentido de la vida, el universo y todo lo demás](https://www.google.com/search?q=42).

<sup>2</sup>Por cierto, el límite mínimo de 6 argumentos parece bastante arbitrario. `ls | wc` es perfectamente válido y útil, y sólo tiene 3.